# Featherlight.js - Allowing for Multiple iframe heights

Tags: iframe, height, featherlight.js

Trying to set the iframe height for individual occurrences - I can set the overall height for **all** iframes in CSS, but I need some iframes fired to be height A, and others to be height B.

I tried using data-featherlight-variant to add a class to the iframes, but it's not appearing to work.

For instance:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" data-featherlight="iframe">Open Google Normal</a> 
<hr>
<a href="https://www.google.com" data-featherlight="iframe" data-featherlight-variant="large">Open Google Large</a>
```

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/80/

Thanks,
Jonathon

Answer (score 0):

try using these attributes: data-featherlight-iframe-width='670' data-featherlight-iframe-height='376'